# Number of imaginary quadratic field with its ideal class group has $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ as 2 part

Tags: nt.number-theory, class-field-theory, number-fields

Let $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$($D$ is a square free negative integer) be a quadratic number field.
Class number (order of ideal class group $Cl_K$ of $K$) is $1$ if only if $D=-2,-3,-7,-11,-19,-43,-67,-163$.

I want to know whether the class number $2$ case is known or open.
My question is about $Cl_K[2]=\{a\in Cl_K\mid 2a=0\}$.

> Are there infinitely many $D$ such that $Cl_K[2]\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: Imaginary quadratic fields with small class number have been fully enumerated, see references on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_problem#Status).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are there infinitely many $D$ such that $Cl_K[2] \cong \mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$?

It's well-known (and straighforward to show) that $Cl_K[2]$ has order $2^{r-1}$ where $r$ is the number of prime factors of the discriminant. Since it's clear that there are infinitely many fundamental discriminants with precisely two prime factors, the answer is "yes".

(EDIT: I added a quotation to clarify what exactly I am answering, since the original post hints at several distinct questions with rather different answers.)

Comment: @WillJagy I've added a clarification of exactly what I'm answering (since the title of the question, the first paragraph of the question, and the final paragraph are actually asking three distinct questions)

Comment: Thank you very much. I searched a lot, but I couldn't find any reference for the fact that $\# Cl_K[2]=2^{r-1}$. Could you please provide me with a reference for that?

Comment: It's come up before on this site, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431499/class-number-of-imaginary-quadratic-fields?rq=1

Comment: Thanks to your result, I thought that we can prove there are infinitely many quadratic fields with odd class number. There are infinitely many $K$ such that $Cl_K[2]=1$. Thus $Cl_K$ is odd abelian group!

Comment: Yes, that's an obvious and well known corollary.

Comment: Are there any known results about the $2-$part of class number of composite of quadratic field $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D_1},\sqrt{D_2},・・・\sqrt{D_n})[2]$?

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments.